# CORS defeats AWS LAMBDA :(

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I've been reading a lot on CORS/Lambda/AWS API Gateway configuration, including AWS's setup help:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html
And this great article: 
https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/

However, CORS is still defeating my API Gateway / Lambda function and I can't figure it out. Would love some help.

The meat of it seems to be that API Gateway proxies the request onto Lambda and you need to set "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" headers in your Lambda function in addition to enabling CORS in the API Gateway, which I've done. I am getting a 200 response and can see the header being sent back correctly from my Lambda function. However, Chrome/FF still give me a CORS error. Any idea why?

Here are my request headers:

`Host: myawshost.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin: null
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive`

And the 200 response headers:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 74
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Fri, 23 Dec 2016 08:35:02 GMT
...`

That all looks nice and successful right? But yet, I get no JSON back from Lambda and this error message in console:

`"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://myawshost.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/view?id=272. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).  (unknown)"`

But `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is not missing! I can see it there in the response.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Chrome is talking to API Gateway and not directly to Lambda. So setting CORS in API Gateway is necessary, which probably you haven't done yet.

Comment: Yes, have done that - followed instructions here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html, to add CORS to API. Tried adding it on ANY and also then creating a separate GET and adding CORS to just the GET. I *think* that that part is working correctly, since it's returning a 200.

Comment: Edited original post to reflect the CORS on API Gateway work done.

Comment: Have you setup CORS on the OPTIONS method? The browser could be making a preflight request (for OPTIONS) which doesn't return the Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Comment: Clarification: was the 200 OK with CORS the response to *the exact same request* that threw the error, or was it a response to a previous test you made?  Also, are you testing your site on localhost or on a real domain? `Origin: null` in the request seems unexpected if you are testing against a real domain name.

Comment: Hm, very strange. I tried the connection just now again - after changing absolutely nothing and it worked from my local dev environment and also from a production environment in both FF and Chrome. It has been about 12 hours since my last test. Previously I'd cleared caches and there's no caching on the AWS side (as far as I can tell from the headers "X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront"). Previously it was not working on any browser - with clear cache. I'd also re-deployed the API for good measure a couple of times yesterday, Well, I'm glad it's now working. But concerned that it seems arbitrary.

Answer (score 4):

I've also spent quite some time researching this, and what made it work for me was returning the following in the lambda handler (Python):

```
return {
        'statusCode': status_code,
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
        'body': status_message if status_code == 200 else 'Failure'
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Hello, i fixed that problem by setting cors and requested headers in
>   Api Gateway

---

[image: On the resources menu, in my method]

> first i set the headers i will want in my **Method Request** after
>   that i want to include them in the enable CORS menu

---

[image: i added Authorization as u can see]

> after that dont forget to deploy the api to public the new changes in
>   the api

---

[image: enable CORS]

---

I hope it will fix it
Regards