# Configure CORS response headers on AWS Lambda For .net

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, lambda

i know have a similar Q/A on stackoverflow, but i need .net solution.....i'm going crazy...
i have a simple lambda using .net C# return input value

```
 public string FunctionHandler(Input input, ILambdaContext context)
    {

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input.Name);
    }
```

this lambda trigger by API Gateway, and also finished all step from aws online document completed! Include Enable CORS and reDeploy API!Still get error

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:7076' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

in the similar Q/A @sqren said

If you have lambda-proxy enabled, you need to set the CORS headers manually:

```
module.exports.hello = function(event, context, callback) {

const response = {
  statusCode: 200,
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*", // Required for CORS support to work
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true // Required for cookies, authorization headers with HTTPS
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ "message": "Hello World!" })
};

callback(null, response);
```

};

Please does anyone have .net solution to help me fixed this problem....

any help is really appreciated, I hope the AWS team is watching too...even though i created AWS Developer Support QQ.....

Comment: `The response had HTTP status code 400.`  You encountered an error. `400` is `Bad Request`.  You would not expect a CORS response in that condition.  The first thing to troubleshoot is why you got a 400 response.

Comment: but i used postman api response status 200......

Comment: Looks like you are performing a POST operation from your application in jquery which is not configured to make cross domain requests. The calling application needs to allow cross domain requests. Can you post the code that is trying to invoke your API gateway

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41298079/cors-defeats-aws-lambda

Answer (score 1):

I think you can enable CORS in your .NET Lambda function, outside of it by going here - https://console.aws.amazon.com/apigateway I picked 'HTTP API' as the API type, it has an option for Lambda and then I pick the Lambda function that I already deployed. As for the documentation it is located here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors-console.html